# compare the way of resolving collisions in hash tables

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

how can I compare methods of conflict resolution (ie. linear hashing, square hashing and double hashing) in the tables hash? What data would be best to show the differences between them? Maybe someone has seen such comparisons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple approach that's also universally meaningful.

That said, a good approach if you're tuning an actual app is to instrument (collect stats) for the hash table implementation you're using in the actual application of interest, with the real data it processes, and for whichever functions are of interest (insert, erase, find etc.).  When those functions are called, record whatever you want to know about the collisions that happen: depending on how thorough you want to be, that might include the number of collisions before the element was inserted or found, the number of CPU/memory cache lines touched during that probing, the elapsed CPU or wall-clock time etc..

If you want a more general impression, instrument an implementation and throw large quantities of random data at it - but be aware that the real-world applicability of whatever conclusions you draw may only be as good as the random data is similar to the real-world data.

There are also other, more subtle implications to the choice of collision-handling mechanism: linear probing allows an implementation to cleanup "tombstone" buckets where deleted elements exist, which takes time but speeds later performance, so the mix of deletions amongst other operations can affect the stats you collect.

At the other extreme, you *could try* a mathematical comparison of the properties of different collision handling - that's way beyond what I'm able or interested in covering here.